# Cellrenderer change cell background color also change value format, alignment

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I use cellRenderer to change my cells (columns) backgroud color but it also make change the cell value format as LEFT columns on image, i'd keep the default format as the RIGHT column on image, here my simple code:

```
DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
centerRenderer.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
mytable.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer( centerRenderer );
```

Thank you so much
here is the image as description above

[image]

Comment: You can use `setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT)`. But this still won't give you the number formatting with thousands-separator `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a custom renderer that will allow you to format the data.

The basic logic would be something like:

```
public class IntegerRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private Format formatter = new NumberFormage.getIntegerInstance();

    public IntegerRenderer()
    {
        setHorizontalAlignment( SwingConstants.RIGHT );
    }

    public void setValue(Object value)
    {
        //  Format the Object before setting its value in the renderer

        try
        {
            if (value != null)
                value = formatter.format(value);
        }
        catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {}

        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

Then you just set the background color of the renderer.

Check out [Table Format Renderers](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for reusable classes that make is easy to create custom renders for numbers, percentages, dates etc.

Answer (score 0):

It may be best to extend BasicTableCellRenderer to add those specific styles back in, as basic would have the bare minimum styles.

```
class CustomTableCellRenderer extends BasicTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // Add style logic here    

        return this;
    }
}
```